# How does this circuit protect against reverse polarity?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I'm looking at the datasheet for the [VND7004AY](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiwtL-x5-LmAhWMHM0KHbthCUIQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fdatasheet%2Fvnd7004ay.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0eiFjg9uIg62eN25zGoGns) high side automotive switch. The diagram below shows the internal structure of the device and claims it is protected against reverse polarity.

I have 2 questions:

1. How exactly does this circuit protect against reverse polarity?
2. The protection resistors in series with MCU I/O pins - I understand that they will prevent latch up in the event that a pin is pulled a diode drop above VCC or below ground. In this scenario, why are they needed?

[image]

Comment: The Schottky diode directly in series with Vcc is a good start.

Comment: OK, I see how that works - what about the protection resistors? Assuming a positive transient above VCC, the zener should clamp the voltage at the input pins. Assuming a negative transient below VCC, I don't see any protection preventing the input pins being pulled below ground. Is this why protection resistors are required?

Comment: There's another diode between Gnd and Vcc.